# Learn different Java technologies without GUIs?

Tags: java

I'm pretty much a beginner at programming and I know only basics of VB, Java, and C++ as well. Lately, I was trying to work on my Java by building some very simple desktop apps but I found swing and layout managers to be very frustrating. I know how to make them work and I've done them before (not saying I'm good at them) but doing GUI stuff just makes me want to drop the whole project. I kinda like the way it's done with VB or C#.

Are there any other aspects of Java or Java technologies that I can work on instead of GUI stuff? Or does this mean that maybe I should just go for C# if I'm in to developing some desktop apps?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, start with the server side stuff first.

GUI need not mean Swing.  If you're doing web apps, perhaps JSPs using JSTL or Flex will be easier for you.

If you develop web services you can use any UI technology you like, as long as you can make a request with an appropriate client. SOAP or REST, you can decouple the back end from the UI.

Comment: Yeach. I think Java is much more better in the web space.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can start with programming some command line programs.  Yes, they maybe less attractive compared to GUI's, but they're easier to understand and get you the stuffs before you move on to the next stage.  I personally don't recommend server side programming for starters because there are way too many stuffs to care about than a simple command line program.  My next recommendation would be webapps, if you're interested.  Because, believe it or not, it is still the most robust language you can trust on building responsive and complicated webapps.

Answer (score 0):

As duffymo said you have plenty alternatives to swing such as JSP.

You can also try a different free swing editor such as [Form Layout maker](http://formlayoutmaker.sourceforge.net/), [Visual Editor Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/) or the one included in netbeans (don't know each one you used).

Also you can try this [SwiXML](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/02/21/building-guis-with-swixml.html) - XML representation of GUI. (never used this one, but seems to be quite simple to use).

If you develop [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format)/AMF3 or Webservices you can develop your interface in many different technologies...

Answer (score 0):

[IntelliJ Idea GUI builder](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html) is really good at this.

But exactly for the same reason you fell frustrated Java is best used on the server side.

Implementing webapps, servers, frameworks. There are plenty of tools to play with.

I think it is just matter of patience. Since you come from languages that don't do very well without IDE it is a bit shocking.

Keep trying